# Execute same command from different views - MMVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, command

I have few Views that represent the same data in different ways (Grid, TextBox, etc..) and in different locations in application.
Every view is bindded to different View-Model.

I have a commands like Add-New, Update, Delete, etc... on the selected row/s. The commands can execute on the active View from a main toolbar (different view), a button on that view, right click menu and some other place.
I don't want to rewrite the commands for every scenario that the command can appear.
Is there any other way to preform it without duplicate the code of the commands and without a massive switch for every scenario.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use the CommandBindings which holds commands in one main place (window for example)
and the call it from each view or control under its scope.
Or create a "CommnadViewModel" which each specific viewModel would get on its constructor and bind to it.
It is made even easier using Unity or other containers.

Comment: Janushirsha, the problem is that I have many commands like that in my app. And not all of the appears everywhere. So the idea of view model for the commands isn't relevant. Also the problem is that the command itself is using data from the view model such as the selected row.

Comment: Hi, indeed the realtions between vm`s are normally the sensitive points in the mvvm patern. there is no need to put together all the commnads, but to encapsulate each conceptual functionality, and inject it with the required info for the functionality, either by an application mechanism(messenger ot something similar) or when invoking the commands vm.